# Log.d does not work on a jetpack compose project

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I have created the default android project using android studio. I Just added the "Log.d" and expect its not visible in the adb logcat output.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        Log.d("hello211", "hello211")

        setContent {
            MyApplicationTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Greeting("Android")
                }
            }
        }

    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Log.d("MainActivity", "hello211")

    Text(
        text = "Hello22 $name!",
        modifier = modifier
    )
}
```

I tried the logcat on both android studio and in the command line

```
$ adb logcat | grep hello211
```

Still could not see. This is the debug build.

Comment: Are you searching for the tag in in the logcat of android studio because it works for me

Comment: Not the tag. Its just not logged. I am grepping for the entire logcat output still not luck. Did you configure anything specially in the manifest or the gradle file?

Comment: No it should work right out of the box for me all i do is i copy the exact tag i give it(hello211 in your case) then in the logcat i replace the package:mine in the search bar with the Tag

Comment: found the issue. I was connecting my device to adb over wifi , After chaning to usb it works.

Comment: Well that's a new one for me